# How do i create checklist in firemonkey android platform?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

There is no `checklist` control into Firemonkey Android Platform , i wanted to know if there any alternative to it ?

Comment: See this example: [FMX.ListViewCheckList Sample](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Tokyo/en/FMX.ListViewCheckList_Sample)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FMX [TListBox](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListBox.TListBox) supports check boxes (if you're asking for a VCL  `TCheckListBox` alternative). Just set the [ShowCheckboxes](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListBox.TCustomListBox.ShowCheckboxes) property to True to show them. To access the check box state of an item in code use the [IsChecked](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListBox.TListBoxItem.IsChecked) property, for example:

```
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to ListBox1.Count-1 do
    ListBox1.ListItems[i].IsChecked := True;
end;
```

Comment: but one thing how to grab the `checked` property ? as example  `listbox.item[i].checked` ?

Comment: Use the [IsChecked](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/FMX.ListBox.TListBoxItem.IsChecked) property e.g. `ListBox1.ListItems[i].IsChecked`.